# Fully-Buffered RAM on a SuperMicro board?

Tags: memory, motherboard, ecc

My home server has a SuperMicro X7SBi board. Currently, I have 4GB ECC RAM (4x 1GB) installed. According to the spec page on SuperMicro's site, the board takes unbuffered RAM. A friend has a large stack of 2GB Fully-Buffered ECC RAM sticks he's throwing out, so I'm wondering if I could fit some in this board to double the capacity? Could I damage the board or the RAM, or would the board just not use the extra features?

Answer (score 1):

No buffered ram wouldn't work on your motherboard as it only supports unbuffered, and they are not interchangeable. However, I don't think "trying" it would hurt anything it just wouldn't work.